# Lena Histogram 8 bit unsigned image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, matlab, histogram

I am working on Lena image (unsigned 8 bit grayscale 512*512 pixels). I tried to plot the histogram using matlab (inbuilt imhist function) and in arcgis. I am getting different pixel count, appx duble in arcgis plot.

What could be the reason?

[image: this is the histogram obtained from arcgis. the first peak has about 4000 pixels]

[image: however the hishgram created using imhist function in matlab shows about 2000 pixels for the same first peak]

Is there some sort of normalization that is occurring in using the imhist function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have a different number of bins, but I can't say for certain without your Matlab code.

Currently you have 100 bins (called "columns") in the ArcGis plot. In matlab you can control the number of bins in the second argument of `imhist()`. In your case it would be `imhist(Image,100)`. By default it uses 256 bins, which whould explain why the Arcgis values are about double.

see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html